# Connection string for Azure cloud database using Vbscript(UFT) with SSL encryption

Tags: vbscript, azure-database-mysql

how to connect to Azure Cloud database using Vbscript with SSL encryption.

I have tried to connect to Azure Cloud DB using ADODB but unable to connect.
Checkout my code to recommend me correct code to connect to Cloud DB.
And how to add ".jks" file to this code.

```
inp_HostName="AZULVSASDB2M08"
inp_Database="DODSM01"
inp_Port="50513"
inp_UID="ABCD"
inp_PWD="******"
inp_schema="LIFEODS"

Set objCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRS1 = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

strConnectionString = "Driver=IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER;hostname=" & 
Trim(inp_HostName) & ";database=" & trim(inp_Database) & ";port=" & 
trim(inp_Port )& ";UID=" & trim(inp_UID) & ";Password=" & trim(inp_PWD) & 
";Protocol=TCPIP;CurrentSchema=LIFEODS"

objCon.ConnectionString = strConnectionString
objCon.Open
MsgBox "Done"
```

I expect successful Connection to Azure DB with SSL Encryption.
I am getting this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFrSU.jpg)

Comment: Is this still an issue? If it is, I would make sure that the Azure SQL Database has been provisioned for Azure Active Directory authentication and that the user attempting to connect is either the configured Azure Active Directory Admin or a member of a Managed Identity group who is authorized to connect.